# What, you're just going to wait for the answer?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

My first Riley; please be gentle.

> My Prefix you must pass if you want to get rich
>
> My Infix is a base, movable or in place
>
> My Suffix is a plant, a stand, a time.
>
> My whole will probably never come

What am I?

Comment: user477343 is quite the altruist! :D You must have earned that badge several times over, friend!

Comment: @El-Guest There's a badge for this? xD never knew, hahah :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you

> waiting for GODOT?

My Prefix you must pass if you want to get rich

> As others have stated, this is GO.

My Infix is a base, movable or in place

> A fixed or movable ODOmeter? Could also be DO, the fixed or movable base of the solfège scale.

My Suffix is a plant, a stand, a time.

> T(ea) plant, T(ea) stand, T(ea) time.

My whole will probably never come

> Godot never does show up!

Comment: You got it! Although I had something else in mind for the infix. Basically, take PerpetualJ's reasoning for her infix and apply it to the actual infix, and it'll make sense

Comment: @El-Guest, what timezone do you live in??? I see some answer of yours no matter what time of the day it is!

Comment: @nikki Toronto, EDT currently (I think GMT -0400?)

Comment: That was rhetorical, but thanks for the answer :P

Comment: @nikki now you can better judge the times I ought not to be up ;p

Comment: Haha! The challenge is to beat you when your are up! :P

Comment: @nikki how did you find my activity log? I thought there was a way to see my activity by time, but I'm not sure how anymore

Comment: I didn't look at your activity log @El-Guest. I just meant you manage to answer many questions and you're really fast at that :P

Comment: @El-Guest It's right here: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/50778/el-guest?tab=answers&sort=newest (Profile -> Activity -> Answers -> newest) :)

Comment: Thanks @geisterfurz007! I knew I had seen it at one point and thought I was going crazy!!

Answer (score 6):

Partial answer:

So far i have:

> GORV

My Prefix you must pass if you want to get rich

> GO, you gotta pass it if you want 200$

My Infix is a base, movable or in place

> RV, or a recreational vehicle, is a sort of a "base" that can move or be stationary. Or if this is incorrect, the infix is clearly [this multifunctional movable base](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LOTQQ90)

My Suffix is a plant, a stand, a time.

> Unsure

My whole will probably never come

> Also unsure

Comment: One of your answers is correct!

Comment: Nice. Also, thanks for bumping me up over 1000 rep

Answer (score 3):

@Cubemaster has already discovered the prefix, and I believe the answer could be:

*My prefix you must pass if you want to get rich.*

> **go**: In Monopoly the board game, you have to pass **GO** to get $200.

*My infix is a base, movable or in place.*

> Could be the letter **a**; it begins the alphabet (therefore it is the base), and it is present in b**a**se, mov**a**ble, and pl**a**ce.

*My suffix is a plant, a stand, a time.*

> I think this is most likely **t** as the letter is contained in all three; plan**t**, s**t**and, and **t**ime.

*My whole will probably never come.*

> A **goat** will probably never come.

Comment: You got another answer! (But for reasons I didn't intend) The answers don't have anything to do with letter overlap across words.

Answer (score 2):

Unfinished answer:

My Prefix you must pass if you want to get rich

> GO field from Monopoly, as others stated

My Infix is a base, movable or in place

> unsure

My Suffix is a plant, a stand, a time.

> Tree (tree as a plant or wooden support, and three as a time)

My whole will probably never come

> Go...tree - what I have so far. I Have a feeling that I don't know the word in question :) A name Godfrey comes to mind.

**UPD:** Oops, it's already done and dusted.